# Ромбическая изометрия. Найти точки пересечения

Tags: javascript, геометрия

Стоит задача: научиться работать с ромбической изометрической сеткой. Подошел вплотную к самому сложному вопросу: определить ромб на ромбической изометрической сетке по положению курсора на экране. 
К сожалению, моих остаточных знаний математики средней школы, не хватает, чтобы понять все те формулы, которые обычно используются, для решения поставленного вопроса.

На данном этапе, мне нужна вменяемая  формула (для нубиков), нахождения координат пересечения ромбических осей, с декартовыми. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные:

- M(x:100, y:50) - координаты клика мышки (на экране).
- А(x:0,y:0) - экранные координаты начальной точки осей
- B(x:?, y:?) и С(x:?, y:?) - искомые экранные координаты.
- соотношение сторон ромба: 1:2
- угловой сдвиг 0,5

Comment: Можно пожалуйста про угловой сдвиг подробнее? Опишу формулы, когда пойму, что значат эти 0.5. И да, у ромба стороны одинаковые. Вы, вероятно, параллелограмм имеете в виду

Comment: @selya, угловой коэффициент наклона, который определяется соотношением сторон. В моем случае получается, что ось  АВ имеет коэффициэнт -0,5, а ось АС: 0,5. Но  если Вы считаете, что эта информация избыточна  - давайте опустим ее.

Comment: ну ок, вероятно, вы имеете в виду тангенс. Попробую описать шаги и формулы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буду во всех следующих рассуждениях опираться на такую формулировку задачи:

*Есть две прямые, угол между каждой из них и осью абсцисс (`X`) равен `a` (альфа, условно), при этом эти прямые находятся по разную сторону от оси иксов. Прямые также проходят через центр координат.*

*Задача: по имеющейся точке достроить параллелограмм, образованный имеющимися прямыми и прямыми, выходящими из точки `M`. Найти координаты вершин `B` и `C` параллелограмма.*

Задача нахождения точек (`B` и `C`) сводится к следующим задачам:

1. Из точки `M` строятся две прямые. А точнее - составляются уравнения прямых, которые проходят через точку `M` и параллельны уже имеющимся прямым (используем определение параллелограмма).
2. Для уравнений прямых `BM` и `AB` составляется система из двух уравнений. Два уравнения - две неизвестные - `x, y` - искомая точка.
   Аналогичную операцию проделываем для другой пары прямых.

А теперь разберем с уравнениями:

(Условимся, что ось ординат (`Y`) направлена вниз, а положительный угол отсчитывается по часовой стрелке, углы берём в радианах).

1. Уравнения прямых, что проходят через оси координат, найти вообще легко. Т.к. тангенс каждой равен `tg(a)=|0.5|`, то уравнения прямых:

   `AB`: `y = -0.5x` (1)

   `AC`: `y = 0.5x` (2)

   Уравнения двух оставшихся прямых можно найти соответствующим сдвигом (на координаты точки `M`) двух предыдущих:

   `CM` (сдвиг прямой `AB`): `y = -0.5(x - Mx) + My` (3)

   `BM` (сдвиг прямой `AC`): `y = 0.5(x - Mx) + My` (4)

   Где `Mx` и `My` - координаты точки `M`.
2. Искомые точки - точки пересечения `AB` и `BM`, `AC` и `CM`:

   Решения первой системы:

   `2x = Mx - 2My` & `y = -0.5x`, тогда:

   `x = 0.5Mx - My`, `y = 0.5My - 0.25Mx`

   Это и будут координаты точки `B`.

   Решения второй системы:

   `x = 0.5Mx + My`, `y = 0.25Mx + 0.5My`

   Это координаты точки `C`.

В принципе, эти формулы уже можно использовать, но прошу, не дайте пропасть всему, что я написал, зря. Постарайтесь вникнуть в тему, дабы в следующий раз хотябы частично решить самим.

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Пока ничего не могу сказать - пытаюсь его "переварить". Какой-то итог `x = (Mx - 2My) / 2, y = (2My - Mx) / 4` очень простой получился, по сравнению, со всем тем, что я видел)

Comment: @Дмытрык если есть возможность, то примерно нарисуйте на бумаге и рассчитайте, сойдутся ли нарисованные точки с рассчитанными координатами. У меня просто нет сейчас возможности проверить.

Comment: @Дмытрык Кажется, что-то не так. Сейчас найду ошибку

Comment: @Дмытрык А нет, все верно. Разбирайтесь, там не сложно.

Comment: Огромная благодарность Вам! Все отлично работает. Если Вы не против, я проиллюстрировал Ваш ответ примером работы.

Comment: @Дмытрык а у вас `Ay` разве не 0?

Comment: Да, да - я понял. Просто чтобы сделать Ау:0, я делал смещение к  Ау, которое, по факту на экране. Изменил комментарий